# Nextjs react-bootstrap onSubmit doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap

### Details

I want to make a form for a register page, after entering the form and hitting submit, the react-bootstrap button will call `handleSubmit()` using `onSubmit={}`.

### Expected and actual result

I tried multiple ways to write `onSubmit={}`, you can see some of them in the `Form` tag. None of them worked. But the third one, `console.log()`, did get executed twice when submit button is clicked.

### What I have tried

I don't where to start debugging this, so I tried way to write `onSubmit` and the function

- Anonymous function in `onSubmit={}`
- Anonymous async function in `onSubmit={}`
- Anonymous function
- Anonymous async function
- top-level function
- top-level async function
- `onSubmit={e=>console.log(e)}`

None of these worked during testing.

### Code

here is a simplified sample with the same problem.

```
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Home() {

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log("test");
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Form
                noValidate
                // onSubmit={e=>handleSubmit(e)}
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                // onSubmit={console.log("hello world")}
            >
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        onChange={() => handleCheck}
                        type="text"
                        defaultValue={"test"}
                        required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Button type="submit">
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the problem.

The reason I use `console.log()` to check whether the function is executed is because I want to print out some value. I expected it to print out in the terminal, but this is the front end, all `console.log()` goes to browser console, instead of terminal. So the code `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` did execute properly.

Play around with the official example : [Nextjs Doc: Building forms](https://nextjs.org/docs/guides/building-forms#part-6-form-submission-with-javascript-enabled)

Answer (score 0):

`handleSubmit` should get a [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log("test")
}
```

You're also bringing in `useState` but no where are you showing how you're using it. You could always update state from `handleSubmit`.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is used in the original code, I forgot to include it in the sample. I tried again in the sample after add `e.preventDefault()`, but it didn't work either.
For `useState()`, it's used by another function I didn't include here to validate the content of the form `onChange`.